# How can I get success and error code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, subprocess

This is my codes:

```
import subprocess

def megaGetFile(fileLink,downloadFolder):
            bashCommand = "mega-get --ignore-quota-warn " + fileLink + " " + downloadFolder
            output = subprocess.check_output(['bash','-c', bashCommand])

            print(output)

inecekLink="https://mega.nz/#!KG4FTKjA!ZF5gOE4HPnvo1Ua3kFg5QK5EvZi15enQ4yCRMs2REtA"      
nereye="/home/pi/Desktop/"
inecek="https://mega.nz/#!PC4xRSqA!vYHRQ1RYEagVWAgtQsGK8QRI3AqS_BjfV2ZV-GP9Vgw"

megaGetFile(inecekLink,nereye)
```

inecekLink is downloading but return code: b' '
inecek is not downloading because I was delete it and return code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./megaCMD.py", line 50, in <module>
    megaGetFile(inecek,nereye)
  File "./megaCMD.py", line 36, in megaGetFile
    output = subprocess.check_output(['bash','-c', bashCommand])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 316, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 398, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['bash', '-c', 'mega-get --ignore-quota-warn https://mega.nz/#!PC4xRSqA!vYHRQ1RYEagVWAgtQsGK8QRI3AqS_BjfV2ZV-GP9Vgw /home/pi/Desktop/']' returned non-zero exit status 247
```

How can i get success and error code?

Comment: The error-handling behavior is pretty explicit in [the documentation for subprocess.check_output()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) and I'd look there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the exception, e.g.:

```
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(['bash','-c', bashCommand])
    return_status = 0
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    output = e.output
    return_status = e.returncode

print(return_status, output)
```

Comment: Then figure out why your `bashCommand` is returning a non-zero status, this has nothing to do with `python`.

Comment: I know why you are returning a non-zero result. I want to get it when the result is zero.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question, if the result is zero then `try` block will continue.